# Git on InstantRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am a beginner in using Rails and Git
I have InstantRails installed and created an app by:

`$ rails myapp`

It created all the necessary files.
I went to the directory,

`$ cd myapp`

then I tried initializing git

`$ git init`

but it said : 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So I figured I might not have git installed. (Although I do have the Git Bash installed already.)

So I tried installing the gem

`$ gem install git`

Then it successfully installed, or so it seems.

But the same thing still happens.

I really need help. I'm getting confused. This is all new to me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, git (ruby gem) and git (vcs) are different things - the former is a ruby interface for the latter. You have a problem with git (vcs). You may have installed git incorrectly - shell cannot find the main git executable in $PATH. How did you install it, by the way?

Edit: oh wait, from the error message I deduce that you are under Windows? I think, you must add the folder where you installed git to %PATH% manually in such case.

Comment: I installed Git msys from Google Code and InstantRails from Rubyforge.

Comment: So, as I said, check that the folder where git is located is added to %PATH% (and that you opened new console after doing so - environment data won't be updated dynamically).

Comment: Yes, I am under Windows. So I should put the path where I installed it in the Environment Variables? Is that what you mean by %PATH%?

Comment: I put the path already in the environment variables and restarted the computer afterwards. I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have git.exe at this path?. And just to make sure, when you execute 'echo %PATH%' in console, is there a proper path to git.exe among other values? Sorry for stupid questions, but I cannot think of another possible variants.

Comment: It's okay. I understand. I am really a beginner at this. But anyway, you solved the problem. The first time I put the variables in %PATH%, I only put the directory path to the Git folder. Until you said it must be directed to where the git.exe is, and so i entered the path again. And it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: For any users that come to this post in the future, go to http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx to learn how to update the %PATH% in Windows